# Elmah within a Web Farm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, web-farm

I've got a project that I'm working on that's going to be running on a Web Farm, we are also planning to use Elmah as our exception handler, we had a few custom requirements that I'm not sure are technically possible.

- We want each Server within the web farm to log to a local database (ie SqlLite, SqlCompact etc)
- We want to have a 'monitoring' web site that would get the combination of the errors from ALL servers (they would obviously have access to eachother through network shares etc)
- We would prefer to use as much of the built in Elmah error handling as possible, ie the Elmah.axd if possible.

I know it's certainly possible to do this using a combination of SqlExpress, Linked Databases and a distributed view. My knowledge of SqlLite & SqlCompact are a lot more limited though so I can't find any information on translating that knowledge across to those platforms.

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Since ELMAH supports SQL Compact, data can be logged separately for each server, but as far as i know ELMAH uses one connection string, which means write is not a problem but reads are as the data is now scattered.

ELMAH codebase would require changes to achieve writing and reading from different databases. And then ELMAH can read from a central error repository.

Comment: Yep, well for the sql express version of it I created a central database that the 'monitoring' website pointed to, within that I deleted the Error table and created a view with the same name which linked to the other databases and did a union all on them to correlate all the data, this way the elmah.axd still worked as designed because it didn't know the difference. My knowledge of SQL Compact isn't that great but would something like that be possible?

Comment: I am also not sure if you can create a linked view when the underlying source is SQL Compact.